# Why do Typescript definition files not protect members?

Tags: typescript

This code does *not* compile if I save it as **`test.ts`**. This is expected because `cantSeeMe` is hidden (I would need to `export` it if I want it to be seen outside the module.

However, if I save the file as **`test.d.ts`** it compiles fine. I would also expect it to not compile.

Why does Typescript not follow the same encapsulation rules when it's compiled as a definition file?

```
module blah {
  interface cantSeeMe { a: any; }
}

var variable: blah.cantSeeMe;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `export` keyword in definition files is optional, since the entire point of a .d.ts file is to describe your *public* surface area.